# App Store Connect Operation Error. Invalid Image Path. No image found

Tags: ios, xcode

Validating App on Xcode is giving me the following error:

App Store Connect Operation Error. Invalid Image Path - No image found at the path reference under key 'CFBundleIcons': 'AppIcon1024x1024' and 2 other errors

[image]

However, I've added all the icons in AppIcon.
[image]

What am I missing?

Comment: Any luck solving this? I'm dealing with this same issue. Thank you!

Comment: nope...still clueless...

Answer (score 2):

So I finally figured out what was going on (for me at least). The initial image I was using was a .jpeg file.

Instead, I went to appicon.co and uploaded a .png image instead (size 1536x1536 px is what I used). This website spit out all the image sizes. When I put them in Xcode for all the icon sizes and tried to upload, it finally worked! For some reason I think the file format was messing it up. Anyway hope that works for you!